# Corrected table name message in dbunit

Tags: java, jdbc, dbunit

dbunit data has been populated with lower case table names as per schema definition. Why do you get a corrected table warning every time, I run the scripts for all databases (h2, mysql ..)

```
[INFO] [dbunit:operation {execution: seed data}] 120 [main] INFO org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet -
        database name=H2
        database version=1.2.128 (2010-01-30)
        database major version=1
        database minor version=2
        jdbc driver name=H2 JDBC Driver
        jdbc driver version=1.2.128 (2010-01-30)
        jdbc driver major version=1
        jdbc driver minor version=2

127 [main] INFO org.dbunit.util.SQLHelper - class org.dbunit.database.DatabaseTableMetaData. Corrected table name: 
        oldValue=user newValue=USER
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually DBUnit does mention this.

Here is the javadoc of `DatabaseConnection` constructor

> ... schema - the database schema. **Note that the schema name is case
>   sensitive. This is necessary because schemas with the same name but
>   different case can coexist on one database.**  ...

I guess DBUnit developers correct the schema name case in order to avoid the problem that might cause by this behavior.

`DatabaseConnection` is the universal super class of all other database specified `DatabaseConnection`, `H2DatabaseConnection` for example.

When a `DatabaseConnection` is created, DBUnit will retrieve meta data about the database, which is an implementation of `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` by the way, from the jdbc connection.

After that, DBUnit will correct the schema name by checking the metadata, that's the reason you always get the logging messages.

DBUnit use following methods of `DatabaseMetaData` to check

```
boolean storesUpperCaseIdentifiers() throws SQLException;
boolean storesLowerCaseIdentifiers() throws SQLException;
```

and here is the implementaion of H2 jdbc driver

```
public boolean storesUpperCaseIdentifiers() {
  debugCodeCall("storesUpperCaseIdentifiers");
  return true;
}
```

so the table "user" becomes "USER"

Comment: Awesome, is there a way to change this except for changing the jdbc implementation?

Comment: I never need to change it, so I don't know. Your best chance is probably to read DBUnit source code.